# Remove decimal values only if all the decimal values are 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, case

I need to select a column removing all the decimal values if all the values are zero.

Here is what the input table looks like, MYCOLUMN is a numeric(18,2) type field:

```
+--------+
|MYCOLUMN|
+--------+
|1.00    |
+--------+
|1.00    |
+--------+
|1.50    |
+--------+
|2.00    |
+--------+
|2.60    |
+--------+
```

And here is what I'm trying to achieve from my select:

```
+--------+
|MYRESULT|
+--------+
|1       |
+--------+
|1       |
+--------+
|1.50    |
+--------+
|2       |
+--------+
|2.60    |
+--------+
```

I tried with a simple CASE statement, but unfortunately it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MYCOLUMN % 1 <> 0 THEN MYCOLUMN ELSE CONVERT(INT, MYCOLUMN) END as MYRESULT
```

The values all remains in the decimal format.

Comment: Just a heads up - CAST is generally preferred over CONVERT where possible (such as here) since CONVERT is SQL-server specific while CAST is in the ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: well, 3 MOD 1 is...3, so that won't find your decimals.  You could check if FLOOR(MyColumn) = MyColumn

Comment: Formatting data for display is a job best done in the presentation layer rather than T-SQL.

Comment: This is because you can't mix datatypes in a single column. You may convert to an int but the decimal datatype has a higher precedence so the int value will be implicitly converted right back to a decimal.

Comment: Thank you Dan and Sean. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below option. But as you can not mix data types in a single column, you can only take this option if STRING output is acceptable in your desired output.

```
WITH your_table (MYCOLUMN)
AS(
    SELECT 1.00 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2.25
)

SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN FLOOR(MYCOLUMN) = MYCOLUMN THEN CAST(FLOOR(MYCOLUMN) AS VARCHAR)
    ELSE CAST(MYCOLUMN AS VARCHAR)
END
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

To represent this in different formats, you need to convert to string.  Hence, you might as well do:

```
select replace(cast(col as varchar(255)), '.00', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, what you need is to cast the result and not the MYCOLUMN itself.

So, this :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MYCOLUMN % 1 <> 0 THEN MYCOLUMN ELSE CONVERT(INT, MYCOLUMN) END as MYRESULT
```

Should be this :

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN MYCOLUMN % 1 <> 0 THEN MYCOLUMN ELSE MYCOLUMN END AS INT) as MYRESULT
```

The difference, the first one will cast the MYCOLUMN to int, then it will return the result as numeric (base type). While the second one will read the values as numeric (base type), then get the result, after that it'll cast that result to int. So, you will need to cast the result to int instead, same as we did in the second one.